# Google Maps - Show address instead geocodes

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have link with geo-coordinates (below), when I reach by this URL to the google maps page, in Input I see my geo-coordinates.
Is it possible to get their Human-readable Address instead of geocodes, without changing URL format (should be used geo-coordinates) ?

```
https://www.google.com/maps?&z=16&q=51.5362671,-0.11687110000002576&ll=51.5362671,-0.11687110000002576
```

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro?hl=en (in general) || https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro?hl=en#reverse-example (for your problem)

Comment: I know about about geocoding.. sorry but it isn't solution.I asked about how could I use without pre-geaocoding.

Comment: you want to convert lat/lng to an address right?

Comment: No, I know about this feature, but I need, pass lat/lng to URL, and get on google page in left side in input Address instead coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood question correctly, you need to use Reverse Geocoding. I found some links. It aren't solutions of your problem but (I hope) these examples help you to find solution.

1. [Reverse Geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse). This page has input where you can put coordinates and check the address. I put coordinates *51.5362671,-0.11687110000002576* and get result: *Carnegie Street (Stop L), London N1, Великобританія*. From code you can find how to get formatted address.
2. [Geocoding Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#ReverseGeocoding). Read about Geocoding Responses: **formatted_address** field and Reverse Geocoding (Address Lookup). This doc also has examples how to get formatted address.
3. Perhaps, this link also can help you:
   [Reverse Geocoding: Get address from Latitude and Longitude using Google Maps Geocoding API](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Reverse-Geocoding-Get-address-from-Latitude-and-Longitude-using-Google-Maps-Geocoding-API.aspx)

If you get formatted address you can use jQuery `.val()` method to set value for input:

```
var address = ... // code to get formatted address
$("selector_for_input").val(address);
```

Here you can find [example](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_dom_html_set) of using `.val()` method.

I know that these links aren't 100% solutions of your problem but I hope you can find there answer for your question.